# Include examples & docs with pip installed library from PyPi

Tags: python, pip, pypi

I have a library registered on PyPi that can be installed via `pip`.  Using a `manifest.in` file, I bundled a `docs` directory and `examples` directory.  The "source archive" tarball on PyPi has this content, but when I execute a traditional pip install, those are not included (at least it doesn't seem so, looking in the site packages directory).

What is the best practice for this?  To not have docs and/or examples?  To put them into a package which setup.py installs?  Is there another path to install such things to other than site-packages?

Comment: HTML docs are usually uploaded to some online resource, like https://readthedocs.org/ and not installed locally. If you mean Unix man pages, these can't be installed without an additional tweaking on user side as you won't be able to write to `/usr/share/man`. The examples can be included as non-python files, either via `include_package_data` (source dist) or `data_files` (binary dist) arguments to the `setup()` function.

Comment: Hmm.  Ok.  I used `include_package_data`, but not `data_files`.  Perhaps that's why pip doesn't include them.  What's the pip command to install from source dist?  Maybe that would do it...

Comment: Try `pip install yourpkg --no-cache-dir`, maybe there are spoiled wheels in the cache remanining from previous install attempts.

Answer (score 0):

You first specify the files (relative paths or globs) in `MANIFEST.in` file, and then add `include_package_data=True` to your `setup.py`.  The files will then be copied to `site-packages` when you install the package.

But I think it's more common to just publish docs to RTD and link to them from your README.  See: https://readthedocs.org/

Comment: Thanks.  I did exactly as you describe, but they are not installed.  I think this may be this a change to pip in some recent release of it?  The docs aren't so concerning to me, but the examples are because I need both py and other sample file types bundled together which are resources for the scripts.